# Check length of an array of objects for a specific value in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm passing an array of objects that looks like this:

```
"articles": [
    {
        "_id": "1234",
        "type": "location",
        "content": {}
    },  
    {
        "_id": "1235",
        "type": "event",
        "content": {}
    }, ...
```

Then I use a ng-repeat to loop over this array where I filter by event:

```
    <div ng-if="articles.type == event && articles.length > 0">
        <h3>Events</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { type: 'event'} track by $index">
                <h2>{{article.content.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{article.content.intro}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="articles.type == location && articles.length > 0">
        <h3>Hotspots</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { type: 'location'} track by $index">
                <h2>{{article.content.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{article.content.intro}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is if there are no articles with type event or location than I'm not showing them.

My question is how do I check this in my ng-if because now I'm checking the whole array's length instead of the array's length for that type of article.

Comment: A solution to this is to have a function in your controller that loops over your array and check if it has at least one object with type 'event', and make that function return true or false. Then you can use ng-show / ng-hide with that function

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr cz i am not sure about this line `articles.type` cz your articles is an array and you are checking as an object.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Yes I see your confusion but in my controller I create $scope.articles where I have put the data from the array of objects.

Comment: @AC3 i have posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in scope

```
$scope.isExists=function(type){
  var obj = $scope.articles.find(function(x){ return x.type == type ; });
  return obj !== null;
}
```

Then try like this

in html

```
<div ng-if="isExists('event')">
```

and

```
<div ng-if="isExists('location')" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
$scope.article_type = function(type) {
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.articles.length; i += 1) {
        if ($scope.articles[i].type === type) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-show="article_type('event')">
```

EDIT: Anik's answer is more optimal